# Is there a difference in use of external lights for taxi in/out or takeoff/landing?

Tags: ground-operations, aircraft-lighting

Will there be a different light pattern (like turning on/off different exterior lights) between taxi in and taxi out, and between takeoff and landing?

Comment: Do you mean aircraft lights, or runway/taxiway lighting?  And for what sort of aircraft and airport?

Comment: I mean the aircraft exterior lights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of beacon, strobe and navigation lights is already covered in this question: [When to use beacon, anti-collision, strobe, logo, and navigation lights?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/64/when-to-use-beacon-anti-collision-strobe-logo-and-navigation-lights?rq=1)

- **Taxi:** Additionally to the navigation and beacon lights, the pilots *always* turn on the taxi lights during taxi. This is not only to see the taxiway in the dark, but also to signal other aircraft and ground vehicles that this aircraft is currently moving or about to start moving. The use of runway turn-off lights depends on the visibility. In the dark, they are typically turned on, but there is no need for them during daylight. The details may be airline specific as well. **There is no difference between taxi out and in.**
- **Takeoff and Landing:** In general, *all* aircraft external lights should be turned on whenever an aircraft is on a runway. This is to increase visibility to other aircraft. There is one exception to this rule: the landing lights are typically only turned on when takeoff clearance has been received (meaning they are left off when receiving a *line up and wait* clearance). Again, **there is no difference between the takeoff and landing roll.** Some airlines use the taxi light switch as a reminder for being *cleared to land* during approach, but it will be on when landing.

Comment: Re landing lights always turned on, that may be true at towered or other busy airports, but not in general.

Comment: @jamesqf You might not do it, but you still **should**: "The FAA has a voluntary pilot safety program, Operation Lights On, to enhance the see-and-avoid concept. Pilots are encouraged to turn on their landing lights during takeoff" (quoted from [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/64/when-to-use-beacon-anti-collision-strobe-logo-and-navigation-lights/102#102)).